# Web Service accepting Object[]. What JSON it accepts?

Tags: java, json, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am writing a web service which should accept type Object[]. Its universal and needs to accept different number and types of parameters in different scenarios.

Request object looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SimilarityRequest {

    private Object[] params;
    private String similarity;

    public Object[] getParams() {
    return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Object[] params) {
    this.params = params;
    }  

    public String getSimilarity() {
    return similarity;
    }

    public void setSimilarity(String similarity) {
    this.similarity = similarity;
    }

}
```

This is WebService:

```
@SessionScoped
@Path("/similarity/")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Stateful
@StatefulTimeout(600000) // 10 minutes
public class SimilarityResource {


    @POST
    @Path("/")
    public List<SimilarityResult> universalSimilarity(JAXBElement<SimilarityRequest> sr) {

        Object[] params = sr.getValue().getParams();
        String similarity = sr.getValue().getSimilarity();

    }


}
```

I dont know what json it accepts for params in this case? I tried `"params":{5,10}` and `"params":{"0":5,"1":10}` and also `"params":[5,10]`. Something throws 500 and something 400 (bad request). Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide some more details about your service such as whether its a SOAP based service or a RESTful service.

Comment: I added the WS code. Its RESTful

Comment: Are you using Jersey? In that case you can get rid of the _JAXBElement_ annotation

Comment: No I am not. Can It be helpful related to my question?

Comment: This is not going to work. You are providing absolutely no hints to the JSON library on how to deserialize your data. Better just to unmarshall the whole thing into a `Map<String, Object>` and deal with that.

Comment: why? I understand the solution you are trying to make work, but I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. Why do you want the request to take the name of the method to invoke (and it's arguments)?

Comment: Because application is modular and you can add some new objects to work with in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully implemented the service using Jersey, the code is the same, I've just removed the *JAXBElement* wrapper and the *@XmlRootElement* annotation.
The WEB-INF.xml file must include the folder containing the *SimilarityRequest* class in the
*com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages* parameter section and the *com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature* parameter must be true.
The service receives correctly the following json:

> {     "similarity": "test",   "params":[5,10] }

The object array contains two Integer values.